# assign value without open excel file

Tags: vb.net, ms-office, office-interop

Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

I have this code:

```
Dim oApp As New Excel.Application()
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

wb = oApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\NoriaMail\23120011\LPO Summary per Month_View 3 - AllMonths.xlsx")
```

can anybody tell me how can I assign value to wb witout open the file
(I want another function to give wb value without open the file)
thank's for help

Comment: Again, what "value" to you want to assign to the workbook object? The path to the document you want to open?

Answer (score 0):

What type of value do you want to "assign"? Some sort of metadata? In my experience, your code above is the correct way to open the file; from there, you can begin manipulating the file.